# Как интеграционно тестировать код, использующий словари ClickHouse?

Tags: .net-core, тестирование, clickhouse

Есть backend код на .Net Core. Необходимо написать интеграционные тесты.
Но, данный код выполняет запросы к словарю ClickHouse. Словарь создаётся из других словарей, а другие словари тоже создаются из словарей.
На текущий момент после внесения тестовых данных и перед выполнением запроса, я ставлю паузу, равную сумме LIFETIME всех словарей. Но, думаю, что это не оптимальный подход, т.к. время выполнения тесткейсов сильно увеличивается.

Есть ли идеи, как это можно протестировать, чтобы не использовать паузу равную сумме LIFETIME всех словарей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ дали в англоязычной версии
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77358369/how-to-do-integration-tests-for-code-that-uses-clickhouse-dictionaries?noredirect=1#comment136379120_77358369

Помогло выполнение

```
system reload dictionaries
```